# jQuery UI dialog doesn't show in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, xhtml

I've finally got the `datepicker` to work on my `MVC` demo site and also the dialog.

I still have a few issues: the dialog doesn't show in `IE7` so when I click a link where a confirm dialog is supposed to appear it just removes the row without showing the dialog.

It works great in `Firefox3` and `Safari`.

Please try for yourself on my [Demo site](http://www.tarsius.se).

Click the link "Boka plats" on the menu. then login with:

> email: test@test.nu
>
> password: tester

when logged in try to click one of rows "avboka" link (this is where a dialog is shown in Firefox and Safari)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ie is having an issue due to line 113 in your page:

```
$("#dialog").css("display", "inherit");
```

I tried without this line or changing it to block and it works fine without error.